# Is it possible in Qt to run an external process inside a subwindow of the main process?

Tags: qt, process

I have a multi document program (call it HostProgram) . I would wish to have a process (call it GuestProcess) managing each open documents inside HostProgram in order to improve stability (if one of the Guest Process crashes I'm not forced to close the HostProgram and the other running GuestProccesses). 
Is it possible using Qt library to render the GUI composing GuestProcess inside a SubWindow of HostProcess? If yes how?

Thanks in advance a lot for any help/hints you will be able to provide me.

Answer (score 1):

If i right undestand your problem, then you can help:

```
    bool QProcess::startDetached ( const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments) [static]
```

Starts the program program with the given arguments in a new process, and detaches from it. Returns true on success; otherwise returns false. If the calling process exits, the detached process will continue to live.

For example:

```
    QProcess process;
    process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
    process.startDetached(/*you new task*/);
```